# Does Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS generate any extra round trip to fetch the newly created identifier?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

JDBC allows us to fetch the value of a primary key that is automatically generated by the database (e.g. `IDENTITY`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`) using the following syntax:

```
PreparedStatement ps= connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO post (title) VALUES (?)",
     Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
);

while (resultSet.next()) {
    LOGGER.info("Generated identifier: {}", resultSet.getLong(1));
}
```

I'm interested if the Oracle, SQL Server, postgresQL, or MySQL driver uses a separate round trip to fetch the identifier, or there is a single round trip which executes the insert and fetches the `ResultSet` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL with PgJDBC there is no extra round-trip to fetch generated keys.

It sends a Parse/Describe/Bind/Execute message series followed by a Sync, then reads the results including the returned result-set. There's only one client/server round-trip required because the protocol pipelines requests.

However sometimes batches that can otherwise be streamed to the server may be broken up into smaller chunks or run one by on if generated keys are requested. To avoid this, use the `String[]` array form where you name the columns you want returned and name only columns of fixed-width data types like `integer`. This only matters for batches, and [it's a due to a design problem in PgJDBC](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/195).

(I posted [a patch to add batch pipelining support in libpq](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/10/634/) that doesn't have that limitation, it'll do one client/server round trip for arbitrary sized batches with arbitrary-sized results, including returning keys.)

Comment: Thanks for providing an insight into PgJDBC.

Comment: It is surprising, but even `NUMERIC (10)` column in the generated keys output disables batching, as backend reports it to have "up to 65535 bytes". That's one point more to have separate thread to read the results & enable proper pipelining.

Comment: Yeah, currently the test is simplistic and doesn't check typmod information. Patches are welcome. But really the whole approach of PgJDBC trying to manage the server send-buffer is wrong, it should be doing local nonblocking writes or managing the jdbc sendbuffer so it never fills and blocks. I don't have the time to re-engineer the driver's buffer management though.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the database and driver.

Although you didn't ask for it, I will answer for Firebird ;). In Firebird/Jaybird the retrieval itself doesn't require extra roundtrips, but using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` or the integer array version will require three extra roundtrips (prepare, execute, fetch) to determine the columns to request (I still need to build a form of caching for it). Using the version with a `String` array will not require extra roundtrips (I would love to have `RETURNING *` like in PostgreSQL...).

Comment: You'd also benefit from message/query pipelining by the sounds. Prepare,Execute,Fetch (or, in PostgreSQL, Parse/Bind/Execute/Sync) is only one round-trip in the PostgreSQL protocol.

Comment: @CraigRinger Oh, I wish it was that simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion even for such a trivial thing a single approach working in all database systems will fail.
The only pragmatic solution is (in analogy to Hibernate) to find the best working solution for each target RDBMS (and
call it a *dialect* of your one for all solution:)

Here the **information for Oracle**

I'm using a *sequence* to generate key, same behavior is observed for IDENTITY column.

```
create  table auto_pk
(id number,
pad varchar2(100));
```

This works and use **only one roundtrip**

```
def stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into auto_pk  values(auto_pk_seq.nextval, 'XXX')",
Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) 
 
def rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate()

def generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()

if (null != generatedKeys && generatedKeys.next()) {
def   id = generatedKeys.getString(1);
```

But unfortunately you get **ROWID** as a result - **not the generated key**

How is it implemented internally? You can see it if you activate a 10046 trace (BTW this is also the best way to see
how many roundtrips were performed)

```
PARSING IN CURSOR 
insert into auto_pk values(auto_pk_seq.nextval, 'XXX') 
RETURNING ROWID INTO :1 
END OF STMT
```

So you see the **JDBC Standard 3.0 is implemented**, but you don't get a requested result. Under the cover is used the
`RETURNING` clause.

The right approach to get the generated key in Oracle is therefore:

```
def stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into auto_pk values(auto_pk_seq.nextval, 'XXX') returning id into ?") 
 
stmt.registerReturnParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);          
 
def rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate()
 
def generatedKeys = stmt.getReturnResultSet()
 
if (null != generatedKeys && generatedKeys.next()) {
     def   id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
    }
```

*Note:*
`Oracle  Release 12.1.0.2.0`

To activate the [10046 trace](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL810) use

```
con.createStatement().execute "alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12'"
con.createStatement().execute "ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = my_identifier"
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL receives the generated key(s) automatically in the OK packet of the protocol in response to executing a statement. There is no communication overhead when requesting generated keys.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on frameworks or libraries to do things that are perfectly possible in plain SQL is bad design IMHO, especially when working against a defined DBMS. (The `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` is relatively innocuous, although it apparently does raise a question for you, but where frameworks are built on separate entities and doing all sorts of joins and filters in code or have custom-built transaction isolation logic things get inefficient and messy very quickly.)

Why not simply:

```
PreparedStatement ps= connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO post (title) VALUES (?) RETURNING id");
```

Single trip, defined result.

Comment: Because `RETURNING` is a PostgreSQL extension and this person obviously cares about multiple DBMSes.